# How to click javascript:void(0) link with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium and chrome to automate the clicks of a page with python.

I am getting stuck not being able to click on the following href link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addSuppData-trigger pts" data-target="edit_3-1" style="padding-right:6px;float:right;">
            <i class="material-icons black-text tiny-small">edit</i></a>
```

I have tried using xpath, css, and linktext to no avail.

sample code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="row-group-1"]/td[1]/div/div[2]/a/i' ))).click()
```

The goal is to click the pen, then select the item from the drop down.
[screen shot of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJQOs.png)

The second highlight line is the pen.
[html tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqDoY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element seems to be a *dynamic* element and to click on it you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.addSuppData-trigger.pts[data-target^='edit_']>i.material-icons.black-text.tiny-small"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='addSuppData-trigger pts' and starts-with(@data-target, 'edit_')]/i[@class='material-icons black-text tiny-small' and contains(., 'edit')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks, though with either of these I am getting a timeout exception.